# unexpected output in binary tree traversal

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

```
func New(k int) *Tree
// New() returns a random binary tree holding the values k, 2k, ..., 10k.
```

I'm just trying traversal binary tree in goroutine and add values to channel. Then print them in main goroutine

Code

```
func binary(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int) {
    if t != nil {
        binary(t.Left, ch)
        ch <- t.Value
        binary(t.Right, ch)
    }
}

func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int) {
    defer close(ch)
    binary(t, ch)
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go Walk(tree.New(1), ch)
    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", <-ch)
        _ = i
    }
}
```

Expected output = `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Result = `2 4 6 8 10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` statement with a `range` clause over a channel **receives** values from the channel and stores them in the loop variable.

Meaning the `i` variable will hold values received from `ch`, you do not need to receive from `ch`.

Yet, you're not using `i`, and you do receive from `ch`. So you'll skip every second element (and you'll also risk getting blocked if there are odd number of elements delivered on the channel).

Do it like this:

```
for v := range ch {
    fmt.Printf("%d ", v)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the suggestion of icza:

```
func binary(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int) {
    if t != nil {
        binary(t.Left, ch)
        ch <- t.Value
        binary(t.Right, ch)
    }
}

func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int) {
    defer close(ch)
    binary(t, ch)
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go Walk(tree.New(1), ch)
    for v := range ch {
    fmt.Printf("%d ", v)
    }
}
```

Comment: Down-voting because this is simply repackaging the existing answer (with no explanation), and therefore is not useful.